# Errors with U2F in Electron

Tags: electron, fido-u2f

When loading a `file:///path/to/index.html` via Electron, I get the two following errors:

`chrome-extension://kmendfapggjehodndflmmgagdbamhnfd/u2f-comms.html Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED`

`Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('chrome-extension://kmendfapggjehodndflmmgagdbamhnfd') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').`

I am not using U2F (maybe some npm dependency is?), and would like to know how to disable/remove this. It doesn't affect my app anyhow though.

Comment: were you able to resolve this? If not what solution did you implement?